# What are bot Standard/Premium channels in Microsoft bot connector?

Tags: botframework, bots, skype, skype-for-business, skype-bots

Can anyone explain what are the standard/premium channels in microsoft bot connector?

Is Skype, Skype for business, Slack, Kik - Standard/premium channels?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See FAQ here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/bot-service/

> **What are standard channels?** Standard channels include Microsoft first-party services (such as Skype, Cortana and Microsoft Teams) and
> services with publicly available Bot APIs (such as Facebook and
> Slack). Please refer to the Bot Service documentation for the complete
> list.
>
> **What are premium channels?** The premium channels allow your bot to reliably communicate with users within your own application or on your
> website. These channels allow you to customise the client experience
> for your users by customising the open source DirectLine and Web Chat
> clients. Please refer to the Bot Service documentation for details.

So:

- Premium: DirectLine, Webchat
- Standard: all others

I agree that it's quite unclear. Someone already created a ticket on Github about that, see here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-framework-docs/issues/113

Comment: Many thanks ! I loved the way you answered my query. Again thank you very much :)

Comment: Hey! Where can I find, how many messages has been sent to & fro from these premium channels?

Comment: @MasterChief, post your question as a real question please, not in a comment

Comment: I have added a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102614/find-number-of-messages-via-premium-channels