# Find number of messages via premium channels

Tags: botframework

As per this [page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/bot-service/) Webchat & Directline are considered as premium channels. I want to know the following things:

- Where can I find the number of premium messages communicated via premium channels? I know analytics section display this info, but this info is captured in appInsights. If I am not using the appsights, how will I come to know this information?
- Is the 10K messages / month for free is separate for Webchat & directline or combined?
- How is it counted? Incoming or Outgoing or both?
- Also, why using these channels cost but not others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Where can I find the number of premium messages communicated via premium channels?

Good question, can't find this figure easily.

The things that I found around this is in Azure Portal, in the following part:

`Cost Management + Billing` > `YourSubscription` > `Costs by service`

[image: Cost by service]

I also had a look to my Azure account details as I am administrator of my subscription, and found another graph with the same value:

[image: Account graph]

It's located here: https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions

You can query the transactions history and got an Excel with the daily items. it's more details, for example one line of Premium Channel looks like this:

[image: Export]

As you can see in the last column (sorry for the size of the capture) there is 1 line by channel by direction.

### Is the 10K messages / month for free is separate for Webchat & directline or combined?

The 10K messages/month for free is the sum of all messages sent in Premium channels (combined).

### How is it counted? Incoming or Outgoing or both?

Given the FAQ on pricing page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-service):

> **What is a message?**
>
> Bots communicate with the Bot Service channels by
> sending Activity objects to the channel endpoint via HTTP POST, and by
> Activity objects being sent to the Bot’s endpoint via HTTP POST. Each
> of these Activity POSTs is a message.

=> Each activity in each side is counted as 1 (so it's incoming + outgoing).
So when you send a message from your bot with 2 calls to PostAsync (for example 1 with text only and another one with a Carousel of attachments), it's 2 messages.

Moreover, I think that special activities like `conversationUpdate` may count on the total.

### Also, why using these channels cost but not others?

I guess it is because those channels are maintained by Microsoft, and they provide a SLA on those channels? See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/bot-service/v1_0/)

> We guarantee that 99.9% of the time the Azure Bot Service Premium
> Channels will successfully receive and respond to REST API calls to
> the Premium Channels API Endpoint.